# How to remove the gaps within flex items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

There is a huge gap appearing in the `div` with the text in increasing with `display:flex`

[image]

Adding extra `div` wrap may not be a solution which may effect to mobile version. **Mobile view should be looks like this**

[image]

```css
p {
  margin: 10px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  // flex-direction: column;
}

.my-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrap-one,
.wrap-two {
  width: 75%;
}

.wrap-one {
  background-color: tomato;
  flex: 1;
}

.wrap-two {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.wrap-three {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-wrap">
  <div class="wrap-one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum voluptates ipsa tempora qui voluptas, dicta corrupti dolorum, iure esse earum ut pariatur, ad possimus facilis consequatur impedit accusantium autem! Nesciunt?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-two">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat commodi aspernatur et! Voluptates officiis nemo corporis delectus pariatur. Cupiditate perspiciatis illum minima, porro voluptas velit nobis ad eveniet modi explicabo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-three">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis reprehenderit, necessitatibus vel praesentium dolorum vitae sequi in magni voluptate alias fugit saepe eos sint dolore quae sapiente sunt itaque, cupiditate.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this supposed to look? You might have to adjust the HTML here. If you remove the `flex:1` from `.wrap-one` it solves the firt problem. Frankly, you'll probably need to put `one` and `two` in their own container.

Comment: Since you are using flex direction column to achieve that output, the only way is to set a height on the container. To solve this properly you need to wrap one and two

Comment: Yep, like this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rwwodM

Comment: @Paulie_D removing `flex:1` make gap with in div https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwwqLv Actually all the color should be fit with in the `.my-wrap` div

Comment: Then you need to be clearer as to how this is supposed to look.

Comment: @Paulie_D As you can see in the image, the gap shouldn't happen. currently the gap is increasing when add more text to the green section :-(

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: @LGSon Thank you very much for your answer. The question has explained more with update. Could you please have a look the updated question

Comment: I updated my answer. I notified Michael_B, as he will be able to show a CSS Grid version. So your choice will be to either use Flexbox with a small script, which has a wider browsers support, or CSS Grid, which can do this CSS only, though has less browser support.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using flex direction column, they won't collapse vertically to decrease that gap, that is not the way Flexbox work.

For flex direction column you need to set a height on the `my-wrap` container for the flex items to wrap, so, in your case, and to be able to have dynamic sized items, use flex direction row:

- wrap `one` and `two`
- change `my-wrap` to row direction and add `flex-wrap: wrap`
- make `wrap-left` a flex column container
- set `flex-grow` on `one`/`two` flex items

*Updated*

To also enable the mobile view, and since that is not possible to solve with Flexbox at all, I added a small script that, based on width, simply move the `wrap-one` element in and out from the `wrap-left` element.

It also adds a class to the body elements, `mobileview`, which can be used to target element in a similar fashion one can do using a media query.

The script's resize handler has little, if any, performance impact as it throttled.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gc5y8xg2/1/)

Stack snippet

```js
(function(d, w, timeout) {

  /* custom variables */
  var flexcontainer = '.wrap-left',
    flexitem = '.wrap-one',
    minwidth = 600,             /* if null, then when viewport is portrait */
    classname = 'mobileview';
    
  /* here happens the magic */
  function resizeing() {
    if ((minwidth && (minwidth < w.innerWidth)) ||
        (!minwidth && (w.innerHeight < w.innerWidth))) {
      if (d.body.classList.contains(classname)) {      
        /* move it back inside the main flexcontainer */
        d.body.classList.remove(classname)
        var fca = qSA(flexcontainer);
        for (var i = 0; i < fca.length; i++) {
          fca[i].appendChild(qS(flexitem, fca[i].parentNode))
        }
      }      
    } else {
      if (!(d.body.classList.contains(classname))) {
        /* move it outside the main flexcontainer */
        d.body.classList.add(classname);
        var fca = qSA(flexcontainer);
        for (var i = 0; i < fca.length; i++) {
          fca[i].parentNode.appendChild(qS(flexitem, fca[i]))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  /* run at page load init resize */
  w.addEventListener("load", function() {
    resizeing();
  }, false);
  
  /* grab when viewport resize */
  w.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    if (!timeout) {
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = null;
        resizeing();
      }, 66);
    }
  }, false);
  
  /* helper variables */
  var qSA = function(s, el) {
      return (el) ? el.querySelectorAll(s) :
        d.querySelectorAll(s)
    },
    qS = function(s, el) {
      return (el) ? el.querySelector(s) :
        d.querySelector(s)
    };
}(document, window));
```

```css
p {
  margin: 10px;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}

.my-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrap-left {
  flex: 0 0 75%;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
  .wrap-one {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  .wrap-two {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
  }
  
.wrap-right {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  min-width: 0;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

/*  for mobile layout  */
.my-wrap > .wrap-one {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  order: -1;
}
.mobileview .wrap-right {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-wrap">
  <div class="wrap-left">
    <div class="wrap-one">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum voluptates ipsa tempora qui voluptas, dicta corrupti dolorum, iure esse earum ut pariatur, ad possimus facilis consequatur impedit accusantium autem! Nesciunt?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-two">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat commodi aspernatur et! Voluptates officiis nemo corporis delectus pariatur. Cupiditate perspiciatis illum minima, porro voluptas velit nobis ad eveniet modi explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis reprehenderit, necessitatibus vel praesentium dolorum vitae sequi in magni voluptate alias fugit saepe eos sint dolore quae sapiente sunt itaque, cupiditate.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution may effect to mobile responsive version if we add extra div

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Then the proper way would of course be to show how that is suppose to look like and we can provide a solution covering that too, as the now used won't work in either device as it won't collapse to its content

Answer (score 1):

First, you're getting abnormal behavior because you've specified `flex-basis: 100%` on the green item (`.wrap-three`), without specifying a height on the parent.

In CSS, for percentage heights to work properly across browsers, you should always specify the parent's height.

Add this to your code:

```
html, body, .my-wrap { height: 100%; }
```

```css
html,
body,
.my-wrap {
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.my-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrap-one,
.wrap-two {
  width: 75%;
}

.wrap-one {
  background-color: tomato;
  flex: 1;
}

.wrap-two {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.wrap-three {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-wrap">
  <div class="wrap-one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum voluptates ipsa tempora qui voluptas, dicta corrupti dolorum, iure esse earum ut pariatur, ad possimus facilis consequatur impedit accusantium autem! Nesciunt?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-two">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat commodi aspernatur et! Voluptates officiis nemo corporis delectus pariatur. Cupiditate perspiciatis illum minima, porro voluptas velit nobis ad eveniet modi explicabo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-three">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis reprehenderit, necessitatibus vel praesentium dolorum vitae sequi in magni voluptate alias fugit saepe eos sint dolore quae sapiente sunt itaque, cupiditate.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second, since you haven't specified a height on the flex container, browsers are free to interpret the height at their discretion.

For a more stable layout, try this (for example): `.my-wrap { height: 300px }`

```css
p {
  margin: 10px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.my-wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrap-one,
.wrap-two {
  width: 75%;
}

.wrap-one {
  background-color: tomato;
  flex: 1;
}

.wrap-two {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.wrap-three {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-wrap">
  <div class="wrap-one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum voluptates ipsa tempora qui voluptas, dicta corrupti dolorum, iure esse earum ut pariatur, ad possimus facilis consequatur impedit accusantium autem! Nesciunt?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-two">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat commodi aspernatur et! Voluptates officiis nemo corporis delectus pariatur. Cupiditate perspiciatis illum minima, porro voluptas velit nobis ad eveniet modi explicabo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-three">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis reprehenderit, necessitatibus vel praesentium dolorum vitae sequi in magni voluptate alias fugit saepe eos sint dolore quae sapiente sunt itaque, cupiditate.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

More information:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)